Using array literal in macro
I have a struct like this:
typedef struct {
  int num_files;
  audio_file files[];
} message_files;

and I want to create a macro so I don't have to specify the number of files of a statically known array:
#define FILES(arr) {sizeof((audio_file []) arr) / sizeof(audio_file), arr}

message_files files[3] = {
  FILES({{1,500}, {2,500}}),
  FILES({{3,1000}),
  FILES({{4,5000}, {5,10}})
};

But this doesn't work: I get error: macro "FILES" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 1.
How can I make the macro accept the array literal as such?

{{1,500}, {2,500}} is not an array literal. What are you trying to do here? Assuming the error in question is fixed, macro expansion would lead to message_files files[1] = { {sizeof((audio_file []) {{1,500}, {2,500}}) / sizeof(audio_file), {{1,500}, {2,500}}} }; which doesn't make sense syntactically.

It doesn't make sense conceptually to form an array of message_files. This is a class with flexible array member (which btw. are not valid in standard C++), so it should be individually allocated for. (audio_file []) arr is also not valid C++ syntax. Compound literals exist in C, but not C++.

I'm programming for Arduino, this may explain the C/C++ mixture.

If you expect that the member syntax audio_file files[]; means that you can decide the size of the array for each instance statically from the initializer list size as in a non-member declaration audio_file files[] = {...};, then that's a wrong expectation. [] in a member has a completely different (non-standard) meaning.

@returntrue It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, even if I take the non-standard extensions from C for granted. Flexible array members must be used differently with dynamic allocation.

@returntrue Also, as a side node, as far as I am aware, Arduino is completely C++-only, but for some reason that I really do not get, libraries for it are often programmed as if it was C-only instead.

What is the definition of audio_file? I feels that you could simply have struct MessageFiles {int num, std::vector<audio_files> files;}; with appropriate constructor, but it's hard to tell what are you trying to achieve. Please clarify.

typedef struct { ... } message_files; is often seen in C, but it not idiomatic C++.

Why bother with macros instead of templated reference to array and variadic templates if C++ is used anyway? What C++ version are you on?

Your code is decidedly a "C" style approach, in C++20 I would do this :
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <concepts>

struct audio_file_t
{
    int id;
    std::string_view name;
};

int main()
{
    constexpr auto files = std::to_array<audio_file_t>({{ 1, "file1" }, { 2, "file2" }});
    static_assert(files.size() == 2);
}

Update to include a more nested structure (no longer constexpr)
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

struct audio_file_t
{
    int id;
    std::string_view name;
};

struct message_files_t
{
    int id;
    std::vector<audio_file_t> files;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const audio_file_t& file)
{
    std::cout << std::format("File id : {}, name : {}", file.id, file.name);
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto files = std::to_array<audio_file_t>({{ 1, "file1" }, { 2, "file2" }});
    static_assert(files.size() == 2);

    std::vector<audio_file_t> temp{{ 4, "file3.1" }, { 5, "file3.1" }, { 6, "file3.1" }};

    

    // This is the initialization you're looking for
    std::vector<message_files_t> multi_files{ 
        {11, {{ 1, "file1.1" }, { 2, "file2.1" }}},
        {22, {{ 3, "file2" }}},
        {33, {{ 4, "file3.1" }, { 5, "file3.2" }, { 6, "file3.3" }}}
    };
    
    for(const auto& message_files : multi_files)
    {
        std::cout << "Message Files, id = " << message_files.id << "\n";
        for( const auto& audio_file : message_files.files)
        {
            std::cout << audio_file << "\n";
        }
    }

}


How does this work when files consists of more than one message_files?

I edited the question to clarify what I want to achieve.

I updated my answer whatever you do don't use macros

If you need to pass an argument that contains , to a C or C++ macro, you generally need to ensure it's enclosed in at least one level of parentheses (braces don't work).  For example:
message_files files[3] = {
    FILES(({{1,500}, {2,500}})),
    FILES(({{3,1000}})),
    FILES(({{4,5000}, {5,10}}))
};

That said, a macro is almost certainly the wrong approach here, and a template function would be much better.

I found a solution using va_args:
#define FILES(...) (message_files) { (sizeof((audio_file []) {__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(audio_file)), (audio_file[]) { __VA_ARGS__ }}


Proposing a "C" style macro with VA_ARGS no less is not really a C++ approach

It doesn't work though. audio_files doesn't appear in your question and as I said in my comments, you are fundamentally using flexible array members wrong. Any compiler that supports flexible array members that I know will complain about it. You can't initialize them with a braced-init-list. Instead they are supposed to cover memory after the structure in an overallocation for the structure via malloc.

Oh it does work. I didn't ask for a C++-idiomatic solution, just something that works for my Arduino project.
